# Support for AMD Thames Radeon HD 7500M/7570M/7650M on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, radeon, amd-graphics

I'm aware of the fglrx deprecation scenario and the availability of amdgpu and radeon instead for Ubuntu 16.04, but the Thames series is not supported yet. I wanted to know if any development is going on and if support will be added in the future.

Also please mention if a solution exists.